# how to prevent \r\n and the likes in JSON string

Tags: mysql, laravel-4, json

I am getting text from MySQL via a laravel model and converting the content to JSON. Unfortunately the text contains new lines and carriage returns, is there any way to get the contents properly escaped?

```
Article::find(1)->toJSON();
```

Gives me an Ajax/JSON error in my view so I was wondering where the problem is. Am I either storing the content the wrong way or am I retrieving it the wrong way?

Thanks.

This is the JSON string I am getting for a test article:

```
{"id":22,"short_title":"Another test article","long_title":"Longer title for the test      article mention in the short title","description":"This article describes a computer classroom where strange things happen and stuf","content":"This is a test article and I think this will generate the error I am looking for.    <\/p>\r\n\r\n Maybe or maybe not. <\/p>\r\n","deleted_at":null,"created_at":"2014-04-25  09:10:45","updated_at":"2014-04-25  09:10:45","category_id":1,"zenra_link":"","published_on":null,"published":1,"source_url":"http:\/\/blog.livedoor.jp\/morisitakurumi\/archives\/51856280.html","source_title":"Some source article","source_date":null,"slug":"another-test-article","view_count":0}
```

The content portion is generated by a textarea that's running CKEditor and it gets saved to a MySQL MEDIUMTEXT field.

Next thing I do is that I inject this into my view to populate my backbone views like this:

```
<script>var initialData = JSON.parse('{{ $cJson }}');</script>
```

And that's where the console tells me: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected Token. As suggested I tested the above string on jsonlint.com and it comes back as valid.

Comment: Don't know if this matters but `toJSON` should be `toJson` - http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#collections

Comment: It doesn't really, the code snippet was more for demonstration on how I get my JSON string rather than display actual code.

Comment: your snippet looks good (with `->toJson()`). what kind of error are you receiving exactly?

Comment: I get 'Unexpected token' after I retrieve the text content via Ajax and that's because of the \n\r occurrences in the string.

Comment: *"and that's because of the \n\r occurrences in the string."* what tells you that? have you taken the string being returned and tested it on jsonlint.com?

Comment: I updated my question with more information.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the problem:

```
<script>var initialData = JSON.parse('{{ $cJson }}');</script>
```

This is where the error happens. JSON.parse freaks out on the string I supply. If I remove JSON.parse it works like this:

```
<script>var initialData = {{ $cJson }};</script>
```

No more unexpected token errors. I was on the wrong track with the problem because I read on so many places that the carriage returns and new lines produce errors in the JSON format.